# Device is not getting registered on GCM for push messages

Tags: android, eclipse, google-cloud-messaging

I have build android application with GCM feature for push messages.
I have 3 devices to test but one of my device is not getting registered. The device that is not getting registered is TAB with Android 4.4.2  Devices that are getting registered are smart phone, one with Android 2.3.6 and on with Android 4.0.4

Following is my log generated for TAB which is not getting registered.

```
12-17 10:39:30.583: W/GCM(15943): GCM FAILED TO INITIALIZE - missing checkin
12-17 10:39:30.583: W/GCM(15943): GCM registration failed: invalid or missing checkin null
12-17 10:39:30.593: E/GCM(15943): GCM failed to read backup checkin config, checkin may have failed
```

Can you please help me find out why this is happening and what is the solution. My bad, that is the device of my boss and i have to show demo on that device.

Thanks..

Comment: please check this code https://github.com/ErNaveen/GcmClientForAndroid

Comment: Do you have Play Services installed ?

Comment: Yes, i have play services installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That Tab didn't had google play app. It was showing in apps but not working because it was disabled from factory setting.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to replace your API key and sender id with the new one there might be problem in your API key and Sender id
Follow this tutorial
 http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Register google account with android device or android emulator.